# How to check ETH contract deposit?

Tags: contract-development

I want to check an ETH contract deposit.

[This ETH contract deposit:](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc4ae4e2444e91b02633cc771468585c954cc444e300ddceb659776287a4bdd39)

```
{
  "blockHash": "0x065e3b474eb1b099a462e5043b906130bf27ed487cc0177a7571b1c059f0bf62",
  "blockNumber": "0x6db0a6",
  "from": "0x8fa8af91c675452200e49b4683a33ca2e1a34e42",
  "gas": "0x30d40",
  "gasPrice": "0xdf8475800",
  "hash": "0xc4ae4e2444e91b02633cc771468585c954cc444e300ddceb659776287a4bdd39",
  "input": "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",
  "nonce": "0xf83",
  "r": "0x4101a528c1a21c320b4270ef42845bb35dcc17dab4fd9036769a3c022ba0343d",
  "s": "0x1e9727d23d54b45b966893cdc13cf16dbaf3c90706cf52cfd2a2d832a298d22b",
  "to": "0x3fbe1f8fc5ddb27d428aa60f661eaaab0d2000ce",
  "transactionIndex": "0xc",
  "v": "0x25",
  "value": "0x0"
}
```

Can I get the toAddress and amount from the input? How?